# Count how many instances the value in a column appears in that column

Tags: google-appsheet

I need to create a virtual column in APPSHEET that will return a count of how many times the value in [ptnum] appears in the data table column [ptnum]. I want it to return the number as value in the virtual column. I need an APP Formula
example

| ptnum | virtual_column |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 |
| 123 | 3 |
| 222 | 1 |
| 123 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula counts all entries where **ptnum** is equal to this rows **ptnum**:

```
COUNT(
 SELECT(
  TABLE[ptnum],
  [ptnum] = [_THISROW].[ptnum]
 )
)
```